# Confused about using Superfeedr to subscribe and download RSS feeds using XMPP or Pubsubhubbub

Tags: python, rss, xmpp, websub, superfeedr

I am trying to use Python 2.7 to subscribe to RSS feeds using Superfeedr.

After reading Superfeedr [documentation](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html) my understanding is that a user can subscribe using XMPP or Pubsubhubbub.

I have previously worked with REST apis however I am very confused as to what I need to do in order to subscribe to feeds and receive them?

I have already installed the Superfeedr XMPP API Python Wrapper and looked into [Superfeedr mashape api page](https://www.mashape.com/superfeedr/superfeedr#listing-subscriptions) and I am still struggling.

What are the basic steps a user needs to take to be able to subscribe and download RSS feeds in Superfeedr using either XMPP or Pubsubhubbub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sofia, I created [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com).
The first step for you is to pick between XMPP and PubSubHubbub. These are 2 APIs with different purposes.

Since you previously worked with REST APIs, I suggest you stick to PubSubHubbub, which you'll probably be a lot more familiar with.

The most important concept of this API is that it's a webhook based system. This means that not only will *you* send us requests to subscribe to feeds, but *we* will also send you requests when the feeds have been updated. We will send requests to an URL on your application, named the webhook or `hub.callback`.

Finally, rememebr that even if you can indeed retrieve (download) the content of an RSS feed from Superfeedr, the recommended way is to actually wait for us to send you that data (via the webhook).